# FPDF print properly currency symbol given by NumberFormatter class

Tags: php, number-formatting, fpdf, currency-formatting

I'm adding a price value, retrived from a db, inside a cell on a pdf created with FPDF, using this function:

```
$fmt = numfmt_create( 'it_IT', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY );

numfmt_format_currency($fmt, $row['prezzo'], "EUR")
```

Considering that the EUR symbol would be output like this:

```
Â â‚¬
```

I've tried to define a EURO costant:

```
define('EURO',chr(128));
```

but i can't use it with NumberFormatter.

How can i print the € symbol correctly in the pdf?

Comment: What values did you use with `numfmt_create` when you created $fmt?

Comment: code added in OP

Comment: From what I can tell the existing fPDF package will not work but someone has created a version with UTF-8 support which should allow you to use the Euro symbol as desired. You will find it [here](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script92.php).

Comment: Yes, tFPDF is looking like the less pain solution. Thank You